# Getting an Objective-C HTTP request iOS 5

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, httprequest, nsurlrequest

I'm needing to use an HTTP request from an iPhone to a PHP script for an app I'm building. The PHP script returns a string of text. I've seen a lot of people talking about ASIHTTPRequest but it doesn't work under iOS5. I've been looking at the Apple Developer documentation but I don't really understand how to use NSURLRequest. This is what I have at the moment:

```
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[req setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://location.of.my.php.script"]];
[req setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[req setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[req setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[req setHTTPBody:postData];
```

Basically what I want to do is do the HTTP request, send an example URL: "http://hellothere.com/myscript.php?options=Type&type=foo then, in my PHP script have:
    if($_GET['option'] == 'Type') {
       //do some stuff and return a string
}

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how to use NSMutableURLRequest or NSURLConnection? Or can someone point me to a very basic tutorial?

Thanks

Comment: ASIHTTPRequest does indeed work on iOS 5. I am using it.

Comment: I agree, ASIHTTPRequest works on iOS 5.

Comment: If you're using ARC it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using ASIHTTPRequest like this on iOS 5:

You need to implement the ASIHTTPRequestDelegate methods. Make the request like this:

```
ASIFormDataRequest *asiRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL    URLWithString:urlString]];

[asiRequest setPostValue:somPostValue];

asiRequest.delegate = self;
[asiRequest startAsynchronous];
```

And then the delegates where you unpack the response. This assumes the response is in JSON.

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {       
    // Parse Data
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
    NSDictionary *parsedData = [responseString JSONValue];
    // Do whatever you want with this data
}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
    NSError *error = [request error];
    NSLog(@"requestFailed: %@", error);
}
```

Comment: Thank for that, I was just being dumb! So, what would I have to do if the response was just a string? I'm not sure I understand the NSDictionary class.

Comment: The response usually comes in XML or JSON format from my experience. I'm not sure what you mean by 'just a string'. But you could do: NSString *responseString = [request responseString]; NSLog(@"%@",responseString); and see what the console prints as the response string.

Comment: The method -JSONValue: takes the responseString and translates the JSON response into an NSDictionary class.